# SharePoint Calendar Class Roster

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, list-form, training

I am apart of a training team at a call center. I am trying to create a roster for the training events as I add them to the calendar page on our sharepoint site. Ideally managers would be able to go to the calendar, click on the event, and update the roster with their new hire's information so that our training team knows who and how many to expect for each class. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a multiple-person column to store the users who attend the class in this calendar list. So the managers could add the new hires to this column by editing the events.

To add a multiple-person column: click create column, choose "person or group" type and Allow multiple selections.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add a new list item content type to the Calendar list with a Multi-Line Text field called "Roster" and set it to append.  Then the manager can edit the calendar event and add information into the roster field.  If the new hires are already in your AD then you could make the Roster field a people field and allow multiple entries.

Comment: At my old job we used to have it set so we could create a new list for each class we would run and then we could add the list URL to the event in the calendar for the managers to go to and add the names of their new hires. I’m open to your suggestion as well but I’m still learning sharepoint 